# Linear Optimization in Math.net

Tags: c#, linear-programming, math.net, linear-optimization

Math.NET seems to have a significant amount of functions dedicated to non-linear optimization, which would seem to imply that it also has some faculty for performing linear optimization, but I've been looking through the documentation and can't seem to figure out how to use the package to do this.

Comment: (1) I don't think they have a nonlinear solver that allows constraints (i.e. they are all for unconstrained problems) (2) it is much better to solve LPs with an LP solver.

Comment: Yes, I suppose maybe I worded my question wrong - what I want to know is whether or not math.net has an LP solver.

Comment: You can put your request here: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/discussions/categories/ideas

Comment: There Simplex Algorithm programs in just about every modern language on GitHub, but you would have to verify that they work correctly yourself. Obviously, some are just someone's homework.

Comment: It might be an interesting programming exercise to write a Simplex program using Math.Net's Matrix and Vector objects, but I have not found them much easier to use for complicated algorithms than regular arrays.